# Online bookmarks website

Tags: webapp-rec, bookmarks

I'm looking for a website to store bookmarks online. I quickly tried delicious but I don't like the interface too much and it's missing some features. I need to be able to:

- Import bookmarks file
- Tag bookmarks
- Rank bookmarks
- Check for no longer valid link (404 error, ...)
- Search in bookmarks by, of course, tag but also by domain name
- Add quickly a bunch of URLs (like "just save it, I will tag, add description, etc.. later)

Comment: webclip.in and diigo.com are quite good but each is missing feature. A website that merge feature of both would be great!

Comment: http://www.mister-wong.com/

Answer (score 2):

[**Xmarks**](http://www.xmarks.com/) appears to be the best at this with plugins for all your browsers so they can sync automatically. (formerly known as Foxmarks)

Answer (score 0):

Try out historio.us. They're pretty new but their search is pretty good. You can also try google bookmarks and xmarks

Answer (score 0):

I looked around, but some months ago I found http://pinboard.in and I have never looked back. It's actually a premium bookmark service, but it has some great functionality that I now relay upon.

The features I love are:

- integration with favorites in Twitter including import
- integration with del.icio.us including import
- integration with Google Reader

..and I expect the person behind to introduce some new features later on. Infact, you can find the list here: http://pinboard.in/roadmap

Well worth the $6 I paid for this service. It comes highly recommended!

Answer (score 0):

check out http://webclip.in

You will love the interface. And it is free of cost.

You can clips parts of the page or the entire page. Also you can highlight app code on the webpage and mark it has code block and webclip will apply code formatting to it.

Answer (score 0):

Right Now I just use Xmarks but for something strictly web based I used to use Linkagogo. It should do everything you are looking for.

http://www.linkagogo.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something that is **more powerful**, check out http://diigo.com/

> If you want more than a simple bookmarking tool, Diigo is for you!
> Compared with other bookmarking tools, Diigo enables you to do so much more. Period.
>
> If you read a lot digitally, Diigo is for you!
> Compared with other information management tools, Diigo is differentiated by its focus on e-reading.

Answer (score -1):

**Google Chrome** have this feature all ready included, and not only that, when you search on google the results have informations from your bookmark.